# Fire event on hit enter and change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one text box when user enter in text box and hit enter it should alert the value, and also if user change the value it should also alert. So there will be two events keypress and change. And I want call this with minimum code. no duplicate codes.

```
$('#txt').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        alert('you pressed enter ^_^');
    }
})​
```

[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tThq5/)

Comment: And what's your problem? Seems like you are already getting there.

Comment: @Felix I want for both keypress and change event. Like user change value and click outside it should alert.

Comment: Then use http://api.jquery.com/bind/.

Comment: Or use http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can list multiple events as the first parameter (though you still have to handle each event):

```
$('#txt').bind('keypress change', function (e){
    if(e.type === 'change' || e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('you pressed enter ^_^');
    }
})​;​
```

*I'm using bind on purpose, because the OTs fiddle uses jQ 1.5.2*

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would approach this problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/tThq5/3/

*Notes: I'm using $.live() (v.1.3) rather than $.on() (v1.7) and also **returning false** so I don't get more than 1 event fired.*

```
$('#txt').live('keypress change', function(e) {
    if (e.type === 'keypress' && e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('you pressed enter');
        return false;
    } else if (e.type === 'change') {
        alert('you made a change');
        return false;
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$('#txt')
    .keydown(function (e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            alert('you pressed enter ^_^');
        }
    })
    .change(function(e) {
        alert('you changed the text ^_-');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `live` approach:

```
$("#txt").live({
    change: function(e) {
        alert('you changed the value');
    },
    keydown: function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert('you pressed enter ^_^');
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tThq5/1/